# How to update OpenWrt to kernel 5.10.165 if I have already manually updated the kernel to 5.10.162?

Tags: linux, updates, kernel

I use OpenWrt and I applied a patch about kernel update, 5.10.162 but now in the master, they updated to .165. But they were at .161, so now they did .161 to .165 so when I try to update my build I have problem cause I've already have the .162.

How I can I update my build correctly?

thanks

- I use ; patch -p1 < kernel.patch

```
Subject: [PATCH] kernel: bump 5.10 to 5.10.162

All patches automatically rebased.

Build system: x86_64
Build-tested: ramips/tplink_archer-a6-v3
Run-tested: ramips/tplink_archer-a6-v3

Signed-off-by: John Audia <therealgraysky@proton.me>
---
 include/kernel-5.10                                           | 4 ++--
 .../linux/ath79/patches-5.10/910-unaligned_access_hacks.patch | 2 +-
 2 files changed, 3 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)

diff --git a/include/kernel-5.10 b/include/kernel-5.10
index da007fc72d..4a573acf8e 100644
--- a/include/kernel-5.10
+++ b/include/kernel-5.10
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
-LINUX_VERSION-5.10 = .161
-LINUX_KERNEL_HASH-5.10.161 = 7aaaf6d0bcd8a2cfa14ad75f02ca62bb2de08aad3bee3eff198de49ea5254079
+LINUX_VERSION-5.10 = .162
+LINUX_KERNEL_HASH-5.10.162 = 2ec400fc50ffdfe4c836a3c02bf6e7aebcd7963dd2ac1425e6d41545c37dd217
diff --git a/target/linux/ath79/patches-5.10/910-unaligned_access_hacks.patch b/target/linux/ath79/patches-5.10/910-unaligned_access_hacks.patch
index 53ddcd46e5..1891a6425e 100644
--- a/target/linux/ath79/patches-5.10/910-unaligned_access_hacks.patch
+++ b/target/linux/ath79/patches-5.10/910-unaligned_access_hacks.patch
@@ -326,7 +326,7 @@ SVN-Revision: 35130
  #endif /* _LINUX_TYPES_H */
 --- a/net/ipv4/af_inet.c
 +++ b/net/ipv4/af_inet.c
-@@ -1470,8 +1470,8 @@ struct sk_buff *inet_gro_receive(struct
+@@ -1469,8 +1469,8 @@ struct sk_buff *inet_gro_receive(struct
    if (unlikely(ip_fast_csum((u8 *)iph, 5)))
        goto out_unlock;
  
-- 
2.30.2
```